# PostgreSQL installation error in debian

Tags: apt, postgresql

I'm trying to install PgSql in the system with following specs:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 
Release:    7.1

x86_64
```

But I am getting an error like this

```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     postgresql-9.3 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-38+deb7u1 is to be installed
```

How can I install the missing pakage?

I tried `apt-get install libc6=2.13-38+deb7u1` and its showing `libc6 is already the newest version.` but still the issue persist.

Comment: what is the output of `apt-cache madison libc6`

Comment: I suggest you update your system first.

Comment: You've got messed up package sources. Post the content of the following files: `/etc/apt/sources.list`, any file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and `/etc/apt/preferences`. Also, make sure you run `apt-get update` after modifying any of these files.